# Strange download speed

Tags: centos, cpanel, litespeed, cloudlinux

I have a problem with download/upload speed. If I try to download a file from my server I have really low speed like 1 mb/s, on this server I have 1 gbit uplink. If I do a speedtest-cli the network speed is good. I tried many methods to download, ftp, wget, http, but the result is always the same, tried with csf disabled too but nothing. I have centos, cpanel, cloudlinux, imunify360, csf, litespeed on this server. After many mtr and iperf3, I tried download file and speed test in rescue mode, and well the speed is ok and I can download file at 100 mb/s. Any suggestions to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: On which side you run speedtest-cli? Which rescue mode you mean? In general, can you structure question so it would be easier to read an understand?

Comment: If I understand your description correctly, you normally get a download speed of 1MB/s, but when you put the client in rescue mode, it's the expected 100MB/s. This is a strong indication that your download speed doesn't depend on server factors, but your client. Since you haven't provided information about this client, nobody can tell you what to look for. Perhaps MTUs or other NIC parameters. I would also consider packet tracing and looking for suspicious timings and resent packets, and experiment with different clients.